# Plugin cannot be resolved to a type issue- cordova-2.7.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have added `Cordova-2.7.0.jar file and js` file in the PhoneGap application given in [this](https://github.com/trigger-corp/Forge-vs-Cordova-Performance/tree/master/Cordova) link. But now i'm getting this error. How to solve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the plugin architecture ([see here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html)), something like this:

Replace:

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
```

with:

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
```

Change:

```
public class PingPlugin extends Plugin {
```

to:

```
public class PingPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
```

Change:

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
```

to:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
```

Change failed results such as:

```
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, e.getMessage());
```

to something like:

```
LOG.e("PingPlugin", "Error : " + e.getMessage());
return false;
```

Change success results such as:

```
return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
```

to something like:

```
callbackContext.success();
return true;
```

Answer (score 7):

I found that in Cordova 3.0 you have to also remove "api" from the import statement.

Change

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
```

To this:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
```