# Compilation errors after upgrading to Cordova 3

Tags: java, android, cordova

**What did I do:** Upgraded to Cordova 3 as per [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification). I am jumping from cordova 2.2 to 3.0. It all happens via command line now and no manual copy pasting of jars/ JS libs are required. I modified my plugin structure as required and integrated each single one via command line.

**Problem:** I faced 'multiple dex error' when trying to build. Googling told me to make sure I do not have two cordova jars in my lib. I deleted the old one. Many compilation errors now. The roots being:

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext; //org.apache.cordova.api cannot be resolved to a type.
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult.Status;
```

I decompressed the new jar (it was made automatically by npm - 3.0 works via Node.js) and the structure seems to be:

```
org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin  //compiles fine
```

I saw similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576579/cordova-2-7-0-pushplugin-cordova-cannot-be-resolved-and-ctx-cannot-be-resolve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877475/plugin-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-issue-cordova-2-7-0) but they belong to older versions. Is my solution correct ? If yes, can anyone point me to an official link where it is documented. I am not sure the upgrade should break backward compatibility this badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you replace in config.xml:

```
<plugin name="<service_name>" value="<full_name_including_namespace>"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<feature name="<service_name>">
     <param name="android-package" value="<full_name_including_namespace>" />
</feature>
```

And in java.class:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
```

Comment: Yes changing the import paths worked for me as I mentioned in my question. I was just wondering why such an important change is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Oh no, Can you read document not careful. Check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins)