# Plugin cannot be resolved to a type issue - after 3.1 to 3.3 Cordova upgrade

Tags: android, cordova

I am having issue similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877475/plugin-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-issue-cordova-2-7-0).
I upgraded from cordova 3.1 to 3.3 because I wanted to use the remote debugging offered in 3.3 and androind 4.4 but now all the JAVA packages are broken for an unknown reason.
having just very basic skill in java I have no idea what is going on.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cordova 3.3 the cordova api is no more in a jar but in a separate project.

If not already done, do `cordova platform android`

Then in eclipse re-do "import existing android project into workspace" and you should a second project named CordovaLib.

If cordova-3.1.jar is still in the libs folder, remove it.

Comment: Thanks a mil it worked the remote debugging also works.
Finally am able to see objects in the log and not the eclipse log.